# Count the number of times record appears within a variable and apply count in a new variable

Tags: sas

SAS - I'd like to count the number of times a record appears within a variable (Ref) and apply a count in a new variable (Count) for these.

Eg.

| Ref | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 2000 | 1 |
| 3000 | 1 |
| 1000 | 2 |
| 1000 | 3 |

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What language? Where do you get these `Ref` values from? Please clarify your question

Comment: This is in SAS, so if it can be achieved in either a Data step or PROC step. These ref values are already in a table but they are duplicated. The entire row is not duplicated so i just want to take the first time the reference appears so by creating this new variable i can just apply a where clause of  = 1.

Comment: Oh, alright, I didn't even know `sas` was a language :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the number of observations for each value of a variable?

Comment: @Tom Exactly that, your answer works perfectly. I didnt realised that you could use the Out option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what PROC FREQ is for.  It will count the number of OBSERVATIONS for each value of a variable (or combination of variables).

```
proc freq data=have;
  tables REF ;
run;
```

If you want the result in a dataset then use the OUT= option of the TABLES statement.

```
proc freq data=have;
  tables REF / out=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achive the results with the below code.
Please note - Data needs to be sorted with a PROC SORT before running this.

```
DATA want;
set have;
BY Variable;

IF FIRST.Variable then counter = 1
   ELSE counter + 1;

RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SAS hash object, you can do it with the original order intact

```
data have;
input Ref $;
datalines;
1000 
1001 
2000 
3000 
1000 
1000 
;

data want;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;                     
      dcl hash h();
      h.definekey('Ref');
      h.definedata('Count');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set have;            

   if h.find() ne 0 then Count = 1;  
   else                  Count + 1;  

   h.replace();                  

run;
```